# (Unity) Как починить тени у объектов?

Tags: unity3d, графика

Столкнулся с проблемой, что задняя сторона всех моих объектов в unity чёрная.(особо ничего не менял, если что оно всегда таким было с самого начала) Не знаю, как это починить. Подскажите какой параметр за это отвечает и как это поправить. [image: Вот фото]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1024&bih=625&sxsrf=ALeKk00_haeL5wJoBpIbIn54j8qjjBJFIg%3A1600458736607&ei=8A9lX_HHJMXUsAeLgK7oBQ&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+ntyb&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEAgQDRAeMggIABAIEA0QHjIICAAQCBANEB4yCAgAEAgQDRAeMggIABAIEA0QHjoECAAQRzoCCAA6BAgAEEM6BAgAEAI6BggAEAoQAjoFCCEQoAFQxyVYpCtgvDxoAHABeACAAekBiAHWBpIBBTAuNC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-light-sources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit -> Project Settings -> Other Settings -> Color Space -> Linear